Horror movie that starts with with two sisters fighting over a doll
I remember an opening scene with two sisters fighting over a doll. One sister is holding the legs and the leg pops off; the doll has marker sunglasses. Years later, one sister gets into an accident that causes her to lose her eyesight and her ability to walk.
I remember something about a witch and the girl in the wheelchair goes to her and says she wants her sister's legs, eyes, and boobs. The sister is on  a chair, I think tanning, then her boobs deflated. The other sister gets the other girl's legs, eyes, and boobs, but that’s all I remember.
I’ve been searching this for weeks and I don’t know if it even is a movie or when it came out. I watched this when I was young.

Hi, welcome to the site. Can you be a bit more specific as to when you watched this?

This is Counter Parts (2014).
It's a 12-minute short film directed by Patrick Rea.

A woman injured in a car accident turns to the supernatural to heal herself.

In the opening scene, two, young identical twin sisters are sitting in a room arguing over a doll. One of the sisters is wearing sunglasses and draws sunglasses on the doll with a marker pen. The other sister tries to pull the doll away but the leg comes off.


Counter Parts (2014)

Then there's a timeskip, and one of the sisters -- Sandra, now an adult -- is in hospital, having recently lost her eyes and one of her legs in a car accident. She resents her sister, Alexis, who's now a famous movie star.


Counter Parts (2014)

While Sandra is visiting Alexis, a disgruntled employee of Alexis gives her the business card of Madame Wanga, a woman who practices voodoo and witchcraft. Sandra then visits Madame Wanga and offers her a briefcase full of money to transfer Alexis' eyes, legs and breasts to her. Madame Wanga performs a ritual with two effigies and a drop of Sandra's blood, and those traits are indeed transferred from Alexis to Sandra; Alexis is lying on a sun lounger when this happens.
There's a bit more to the story, but I won't spoil it, since you didn't mention it.
The full short film can currently be watched for free here.

It is!! It was counter parts thank you so much!  Thank you thank you

@koko - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.
